# Confusing about を that has no verb in article

Tags: grammar, particle-を

I'm reading this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011580241000/k10011580241000.html) and I do not understand why the bolded **を** exists. I'm am expecting a verb such as する, but there isn't one. How is the **を** functioning here or why is there no verb paired with it?

> アメリカのトランプ大統領は、自分のことを悪く書く新聞やテレビ**を**「うそのニュース」や「国民の敵」だと言っています。
>
> My Translation: American president Trump says that things like news papers and TV who write poorly about his matters are "Fake News".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No verb?  Isn't 「言っています」 a verb (phrase)?

> 「Person + は + Object/Another Person + を/のことを + "Name" + と/だと/って + 言う/言っている, etc.」

is an extremely common expression meaning:

> "(Person) calls/is calling (Object/Another Person) "(Name)"."

「言う」 means "to call" in this expression and you will keep encountering this construct for as long as you study Japanese.

> "U.S. President Trump calls the newspapers and TV (stations) that speak ill of him 'Fake News' or 'enemies of the people'."

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking that only a verb could follow を. Also did't realize「うそのニュース」や「国民の敵」だと言っています was a verb phrase either

Answer (score 0):

The verb is だ, not 言う.

テレビを「敵」だと大統領は言う。
The president says that the TV is the enemy.

You can replace を with が:
テレビが「敵」だと大統領は言う。

テレビが「敵」だ(the TV is the enemy) is one sentence with だ as a verb.

大統領は言う(the president says) is another sentence.